# S3 to local hdfs data transfer using Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I have installed Apache hadoop on my local system and want to import data from Amazon s3 using Sqoop.
Is there any way to achive this.
If yes kindly help me how can i achieve this.
Examples would be much appreciated.
Please help me as soon as possible.

Note:I am not using Amazon EMR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqoop is for getting data from relational databases only at the moment.
Try using "distcp" for getting data from S3.

The usage is documented here: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3 In the section "Running bulk copies in and out of S3"